# How To Prevent Adding Duplicate Value in Sqlite Database?

Tags: database, sqlite, duplicates

In My LoginActivity i want to save to username and password to database. so while login i save the login data to a string and sent it to database using insertRecord method.

here is the code:

```
   String userid = username.getText().toString();
    String password = userPassword.getText().toString();
    LoginDbHelper LoginDbHelper = new LoginDbHelper(this);
    LoginDbHelper.insertRecord(userid,password);
```

then i catch the data in database using the insertRecoard params.
here what i did in my database:

```
public void insertRecord(String userid, String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase dbc = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(Username, userid);
            values.put(Password, password);
            //  Log.e("Values are ", String.valueOf(values));
            //dbc.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        dbc.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME, null, values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "database " + values, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dbc.close();

        }
```

but every time user login there is another row added in my table.
i don't want the duplicate value. please help.

Comment: The login activity's purpose is to check and verify that a user's credentials are valid. Why do you use it to insert data?

Comment: i was told to store username and password in my database. so i use insertrecord to store data but is there any query or something(code) that will prevent to store same data only once.

Answer (score 0):

i used Courser in my DbHelper like this :

```
public Cursor alldata(){
    SQLiteDatabase dbs = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbs.rawQuery("select * from login_details", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

then i use it when database is empty like this:

```
String userid = username.getText().toString();
String password = userPassword.getText().toString();

//database cursor
dbs = new LoginDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
Cursor cursor = dbs.alldata();
if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
    LoginDbHelper LoginDbHelper = new LoginDbHelper(this);
    LoginDbHelper.insertRecord(userid,password);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```